# Can I Use The INCLUDE LAYOUT To ScrollView In My Activity?

Tags: android, android-layout, scrollview, android-toolbar

Good day, I'm having a problem with my xml layout. I create an another xml file `share_app_scroll(ScrollView Layout)` and included it in my `ShareApp.xml` .

**The Problem is, my toolbar/action bar don't appear. All I can see, is my `scrollview layout` that I created. Is this possible to include the `scrollView layout`?**. Here's my Code.

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context=".activities.ShareAppActivity">

<!--Include ActionBar/Toolbar-->
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:elevation="8dp"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary">
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    <include
        android:id="@+id/share_scrollview"
        layout="@layout/share_extend_scrollview"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"/>
```

[image: MissingToolbar]

Sorry for the blurred picture.
Thank you in advanced.

Comment: align include layout below toolbar

Comment: you are add  toolbar in java file?

Comment: @VivekMishra - Thank you, I just forgot to drag the included scrollViewLayout - to below the toolbar. It appears no problem in the preview.  Haha.. many Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using relative layout as your parent layout therefore you have to align your include layout below toolbar.Like this

```
    <include
            android:id="@+id/share_scrollview"
            layout="@layout/share_extend_scrollview"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem will be in the manifest file. 
Check if the java file for your xml has a android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" in the manifest. remove the no action bar and it will appear. if you are talking about during the design view. next to the api level there is app theme. change that to any except .NoactionBar